# Am I getting the right output for tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create my own depthwise separable convolution, and I want to test it against the tensorflow implementation, but I cant tell if I got it to work properly. Here is my code

First I create the image and the depth filter. The image is 2 channels, each one being 3x3. The filter is also 2 channels, 3x3. The filters on both filters have the same values, while the image channels have slightly different values.

```
depth_filter = np.array([   [[0,-1,0],[-1,5,-1],[0,-1,0]],
                                [[0,-1,0],[-1,5,-1],[0,-1,0]]], 
                            np.float32)
image = np.array([  [[102,109,124],[99,98,98],[103,103,98]],
                        [[101,108,123],[98,97,97],[102,102,97]]], 
                        np.float32)
```

Then I set some variables to make it a little easy on myself.

```
C = image.shape[0]
H = image.shape[1]
W = image.shape[2]
R_H = depth_filter.shape[1]
R_W = depth_filter.shape[2]
```

Then I reshape my matrices so they can be used in tensorflow's implementation.

```
kernel = tf.reshape(depth_filter, [R_H,R_W,C,1], name='kernel')
imageconv = tf.reshape(image, [1,H,W,C], name='imageconv')
dout = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(imageconv, kernel, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
```

The issue is that I get this output

```
[[[-325.    0.]
  [-407.  406.]
  [-206.  406.]]

 [[ 327. -208.]
  [  85.   76.]
  [-199.  212.]]

 [[ 393. -204.]
  [ 438. -424.]
  [   0. -326.]]]
```

I was expecting to get 2 3x3 matrices, where channel 1 on the kernel would filter the channel 1 image, and channel 2 on the kernel would filter the channel 2 image. When I have just 1 channel for each, I get 1 3x3 image. Am I not understanding how depthwise convolution works or did I do something wrong.